# Can I have multiple levels of pop up windows using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items page as main page. It lists all of the items. When user tries to edit an item, I provide a pop up window using modal("show") to display the item's detail. Everything works fine at this point. But if I tried to add another pop up from the current item's detail pop up, the item's detail pop up window becomes hidden. I just want to check if having multiple levels of pop up is feasible.

Thanks!

Comment: Post you Minimal code please

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a little script for just that issue as our engineers are modal happy over here...

```
// Insure: Multiple dialogs overlay properly
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var models = $('.modal-backdrop').length;
    var new_z_index = (models * 10) + 1030;
    if (models > 1) {
        $('.modal-backdrop:last').attr("style", "z-index:" + new_z_index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: just put that in your dom ready on any pages you want to ensure never losing most recent modal overlays.